# How to store data in realtime database in firebase during user registration?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm making socialmedia-like app that has user profile. I want to save their profile data upon their registration using their uid. Although the registration is successful, profile is not saving in the firebase database. I've also checked the rules, and read and write is set for authenticated users.

Here's my code:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button btn_reg;
private EditText etName, etEmail, etPassword, etCPassword, etMobile, etSchoolCompany, etLocation;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    btn_reg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    etName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    etCPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCPassword);
    etMobile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMobile);
    etSchoolCompany = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSchoolCompany);
    etLocation = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etLocation);

    btn_reg.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick (View view){
    if(view == btn_reg){
        registerUser();
    }
}

private void registerUser(){
    String name = etName.getText().toString();
    String mobile = etMobile.getText().toString();
    String SchoolCompany = etSchoolCompany.getText().toString();
    String location = etLocation.getText().toString();
    final String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    String cpassword = etCPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering..");
    progressDialog.show();

    //REGISTERING USER
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        //THIS IS FOR STORING AUTHENTICATED USER'S DATA
                        final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com");
                        ref.authWithPassword(email, password, new Firebase.AuthResultHandler(){
                            @Override
                            public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData){
                                // Authentication just completed successfully :)
                                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                map.put("provider", authData.getProvider());
                                if(authData.getProviderData().containsKey("displayName")) {
                                    map.put("displayName", authData.getProviderData().get("displayName").toString());
                                }
                                ref.child("users").child(authData.getUid()).setValue(map);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError error) {
                //ERRORS TODO
                            }
                        });
                        progressDialog.hide();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration failed, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            });
}


}
```

Comment: you can look at the logcat, check if there's `permission denied` warning after this line `ref.child("users").child(authData.getUid()).setValue(map);`

Comment: @Wilik Nope, I didn't see any permission denied on logcat.. However, I saw this `D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.` might give you a hint maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [createUserWithEmailAndPassword method reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

> Tries to create a new user account with the given email address and password. **If successful, it also signs the user in into the app.**

That means you don't need to authenticate the user again after the signup process completed.

To make sure that the task is complete and the `firebaseUser` is not null, better add `AuthStateListener` to your `FirebaseAuth` instead of saving data inside `onComplete` method, the code is in [the official guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth)

Then you can save the data if the user is authenticated.

```
public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("provider", user.getProviders().get(0));
        if(user.getProviderData().containsKey("displayName")) {
            map.put("displayName", user.getProviderData().get("displayName").toString());
        }
        ref.child("users").child(user.getUid()).setValue(map);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late response.. I found your answer helpful however, I didn't used map, instead I used POJO as I've read from other guides that's what experts recommend. :)

Comment: yeah agree, POJO is better. It's just easier to give example in Map. Cheers :)

Comment: i  m getting inside block task.isSuccessfull ----> false but still its calling onAuthStateChanged method as well

Comment: your solution not help me it is missing some keys and values and i am not able to solve

Answer (score 2):

Suppose if you want to add the user name on database then write

```
String name = etName.getText().toString().trim();
```

then Simply create object of `DatabaseReference` class eg:

```
 DatabaseReference myRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

 DatabaseReference userNameRef =  myRootRef.child("User Name");

 userNameRef.setValue(name);

// to add email
String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
DatabaseReference userEmail = myRootRef.child("Email ");
userEmail.setValue(email);
```

In the same way you can do it for rest of the things

This will store the data as JSON tree where the root is `myRootRef` and its child will be `userNameRef`

Comment: How can I check if the proposed email has already been registered?

Comment: @Ethan I think you need to authenticate it, see my code above.. below the line `//THIS IS FOR STORING AUTHENTICATED USER'S DATA`.. I think that's how you check if your email is already registered. Or if you're error handling if the email is already registered, kindly check [Full Error Listing](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/user-auth.html#section-full-error)

Comment: I tried it `private void reguser(){
        String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        myRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference RootUsers =  myRootRef.child("users");
        RootUsers.setValue(email);
    }` but I'm getting error ` java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase;` on line of myRootRef

Comment: @Gian7 are you sure if firebase database is properly synchronized in your project?

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay Yes, I believe it is so.. I've compared my version to several tutorials and guides provided in firebase documentation. Do you want me to double check onto something (dependencies, etc.) to make sure? By the way, here's my [Firebase database structure](http://i68.tinypic.com/ncb246.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having a similar problem, a common cause of data not being persisted in Firebase is the child name in `Realtime Database|Rules` not matching the name in your java code:

[image]

Java code:

[image]

Again, you should be calling:

`ref.child("users").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(<YOUR_POJO_OBJECT>);`

instead of

```
 ref.child("users").child(authData.getUid()).setValue(map);
```