# How to retrieve user email from Firebase Authentication to Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm currently using Firebase email authentication as the sign in method. However, when I register new user, the email of the new user will only save to the Authentication panel rather than my Realtime Database. And now I would like to add on more information for the particular user. What should I do now?

Is there a way whenever new user is registered, the email of the new user will save to the Authentication panel *and* Realtime Database?

I have no idea how to retrieve the user email from Authentication. 
I know there might be a way to get the user email which is by using "user UID"? But may I know how to do it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39077364/209103, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41531764/209103, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38682667/209103 and possibly some more from [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-authentication%5d%5bandroid%5d%20save%20user%20to%20database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly add the email of the user while signup using the following line of code.Call the code inside mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword().Set the email from the edit text.

```
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("my_users_email")
                                    .child(task.getResult().getUser().getUid())
                                    .child("Email").setValue(Email.getText().toString());}
```

Comment: What if I would like to add the data of username? May I know how to do it?

Comment: use Username.getText().toString()  inside setValue() .Where Username represent the edit text in which user name is entered.